# Why doesn't postgres accept function argument as table name

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying the update a table using the function below. The table name is a function argument. Running this function results in the error:

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1:  (SELECT * FROM  $1  ORDER BY  $2 )`

I tried using the EXECUTE statement and the quote_ident function, but without success sofar. I'm sure I'm overlooking something simple...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createdefaultorder(table_name varchar, sort_column varchar)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  rRec RECORD;
  counter integer := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR rRec IN  (SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY sort_column)  LOOP
    UPDATE table_name SET row_number = counter WHERE id = rRec.id;
    counter := counter + 1;
  END LOOP; 
  RETURN 0;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please either accept an answer or update your question. The code you provided does not appear relevant to the error you posted at the top.

Answer (score 5):

Using `EXECUTE` and `quote_ident` is the correct solution.  If you have trouble with that, you might want to show that code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I managed the get the required result with the following function:
`
BEGIN
  FOR rRec IN  EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' ORDER BY ' || quote_ident(sort_column)   LOOP
    EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' SET row_number = ' || counter || ' WHERE id = ' || rRec.id;
    counter := counter + 1;
  END LOOP; 
  RETURN 0;
END;
`

Answer (score 0):

`Execute` and `quote_ident` are  the solution to that problem: [PostgreSQL 8.4 Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/plpgsql-statements.html)

Answer (score 0):

You must use EXECUTE and quote_ident() in a dynamic query execution like this:

```
BEGIN FOR rRec IN EXECUTE 'SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' ORDER BY ' || quote_ident(sort_column) LOOP EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || quote_ident(table_name) || ' SET row_number = ' || counter || ' WHERE id = ' || rRec.id; counter := counter + 1; END LOOP; RETURN 0; END;
```